# Nativescript hot reload JS code

Tags: nativescript

While i can hot reload XML in Nativescript i am unable to hot reload JS changes.  Is this even possible?

I run 'tns livesync ios --emulator --watch'.

My editor is Visual Source Code and I use the NS plugin for it.

Thanks!

Comment: It should definitely work, you don't have TypeScript installed, do you? Would really need more info to make any useful suggestions, system info software versions etc.

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript itself does not yet support hot-reloading of JS files as of version 2.20.

There is a plugin called **nativescript-liveedit** that allows hot reloading of JS on the Android platform.   The plugin is not "perfect" but; it works in the majority of the cases and allows you to configure related files and files to auto-restart on (i.e. if you change a singleton)

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of the plugin)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I followed the instructions but I can't get it to run.  When I install the plugin i get '2.1.1 for android is not compatible with the currently installed framework version 1.7.1'..  Not sure which version your script is referring to.  'tns --version' gives me 2.1.1.  When i run 'node watcher' i get 'Cannot find module '/Users/geo/nativescript-bluetooth-demo/Bluetooth/watcher''.  Does this command launches'native script-liveedit/support/watcher.js'?  Many thanks!

Comment: The NativeScript-LiveEdit is one of the few plugins that is built for each version of NativeScript; so if you are currently using the runtimes v1.7.1 rather than 2.1.1; then you need to install it as: tns plugin add nativescript-liveedit@1.7.1 to get the 1.7.1 version.

Comment: I believe if it fails, the watcher is not installed.   (Sorry, been a while since I worked on the install script).  But if it is installed you should be in the root project folder, and then you can type "node watcher" and it should run.